# snappass proxy setup either https or http

Tags: python, apache, nginx, flask, webserver

IS anyone implemented snappass in production deployment Please share the configuration setup proxy method.
Need redirect snappass URL HTTP  Running on **http://0.0.0.0:5000/** need to redirect to HTTPS using Nginx or Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I configured Reverse proxy for the Snappass URL. Here the below webserver config.

> `

```html
[root@snappasstest ~]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/snappasstest.conf
 ServerTokens Prod
 ServerSignature Off
 TraceEnable off
Listen snappass:443
<VirtualHost snappass:443>
    ServerName snappass
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|OPTIONS)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    SSLEngine      On
    SSLProtocol   all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCipherSuite 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256'
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCompression      off
    SSLSessionTickets   off
    Loglevel debug
    # Set the path to SSL certificate
    # Usage: SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl-key.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt-ca.crt
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/snappass-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/snappass-access.log" combined
    <Directory />
     Options -Indexes
    <LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
        deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
    ProxyPass /  http://snappass:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://snappass:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

`